# Generalization of the existing problem "A fly on a triangle"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I encountered with special case of problem which I generalized in the following way:

Let $P_n$ be a polygon with $n$ vertexes $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$. We denote center of $P_n$ as $O$. Let us connect each vertex with $O$. So we have $2n$ lines. Suppose that there is a fly which is, for example, in vertex $v_1$ at the moment. Also there is a spider which in $O$ and wants to eat the fly. Spider cannot move. But fly has to move always. At each vertex $v_i$ fly chooses *randomly* where to go. So fly has 3 options: to the left, to the right or to the spider. Therefore, each choice may emerge with equal probability equal to $\frac13.$ The question is:

*What is the probability $\mathbb{S}_n$ for the fly to return to the initial vertex $v_1$? And what is the limit of $\mathbb{S}_n$ when $n \to \infty$*

I have solved this for cases $n = 2, 3, 4$. But for larger $n$ my method does not work.

Comment: I guess the closed form of $\mathbb S$ either doesn't exist or at least isn't known. Asymptotic behaviour probably can be figured out though.

Comment: I can describe the method I used to solve special cases of it. May be you will change your opinion.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $\mathbb{S}_n$?  I can't tell if you're asking for the probability of being at $v_1$ at step $n$, or the probability of having returned to $v_1$ at least once by step $n$, but not necessarily being there at step $n$.

Comment: @Mathily If I get it correctly, this is the probability of ever returning to $v_1$, not under a constrained number of steps.

Comment: Yes. It is just probability of ever returning to $v_1$. And $n$ indicates that there are $n$ vertexes in polygon $P_n$

Comment: You could model this setup as a Markov chain with 2 absorbing states and an initial distribution based on the probability distribution after 1 step.  I tend to suspect that you won't get a nice closed form, but you might.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try.

Comment: Consider the following heuristic: the probability of the fly having went a full circle is exponentially small, so the only "dominating term" comes from coming back the way it started. So we may approximately model this using a line instead. Suppose the fly went from $v_1$ to $v_2$, and label further vertices $v_3,v_4,\dots$. Let $x_k$ be probability of returning to $v_1$ starting from $v_k$. Then $v_1=1$ and $v_i=(v_{i-1}+v_{i+1})/3$. This also decays exponentially, so for computational purposes, we may assume $x_n=0$ for some large $n$. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: Solving a large system of linear equations which arises this way using Sage one finds overwhelming numerical data implying $x_2=1/\varphi^2$. Hence the probability of returning to $v_1$ at all is $2/(3\varphi^2)$ (at the first step we don't want to be eaten by the spider, and then we have the above model). So we should have $\mathbb S_n\rightarrow 2/(3\varphi^2)$.

Comment: In your previous comment where $x_k$ is used except its definition? And what is $\varphi$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit the first comment anymore. It should say $x_1=1,x_i=(x_{i-1}+x_{i+1})/3$. $\varphi$ is the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: It is interesting answer. Could you explain it in detail please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my great surprise, a closed form exists. First I will explain the proof and later how I found it. Note that I will be using (elementary) linear algebra. For simplicity, I will denote the vertices $v_0,\dots,v_{n-1}$, so keep that in mind.

**Claim:** Let $P(k,n)$ be the probability of the fly returning to $v_0$ starting from $v_k$. Then:

- if $n$ is even and $0\leq k\leq \frac{n}{2}$, then 
  $$P(k,n)=P(n-k,n)=\frac{L_{n+1-2k}}{L_{n+1}},$$
  and
- if $n$ is odd and $0\leq k<\frac{n}{2}$, then
  $$P(k,n)=P(n-k,n)=\frac{F_{n+1-2k}}{F_{n+1}},$$

where $F_n$ and $L_n$ are, respectively, the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.

**Proof:** Note that numbers $P(k,n)$ for $k=2,\dots,n-2$ the linear equations
$$P(k,n)=\frac{P(k-1,n)+P(k+1,n)}{3}$$
and also
$$P(1,n)=\frac{1+P(2,n)}{3}\qquad P(n-1,n)=\frac{P(n-2,n)+1}{3}.$$
Writing this system of $n-1$ linear equations in $n-1$ variables a matrix form we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
-1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots & \frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \dots & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right).$$
The block on the left is easily seen to be invertible, so this system of equations has a unique solution. Check that the numbers written in the statement of the claim satisfy the equalities (this is easy, but mildly tedious; the key formulas are $F_{n+4}=3F_{n+2}-F_n,L_{n+4}=3L_{n+2}-L_n$). $\square$

It follows that $\mathbb S_n=\frac{1}{3}P(1,n)+\frac{1}{3}P(n-1,n)$, which by the claim is either $\frac{2F_{n-1}}{3F_{n+1}}$ or $\frac{2L_{n-1}}{3L_{n+1}}$. In particular, the limit is
$$\frac{2}{3\varphi^2}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3}$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Now, how in the world have I came up with the numbers? The answer: I have computed them. Not by hand, of course, but with the help of SageMath, free mathematical software akin to Mathematica (you can check out the online version [here](https://cloud.sagemath.com/)).

I have written the following script which, first, builds the matrix of the system of equations described in the above proof, and then, essentially, solves it (more precisely, it reduces it to the *row echelon form* from which we can read of the (negatives of) the solutions in the last column).

```
for n in range(3,20):
M = MatrixSpace(QQ,n,n+1)
B = M([0]*(n*(n+1)))
for i in range(n):
    B[i,i] = -1
    B[i,i-1] = 1/3
    B[i,i+1] = 1/3
-B.echelon_form()
```

How did I then figure out that we are dealing with Fibonacci and Lucas? I have recognized Fibonacci numbers almost immediately (the slight issue is that the fractions are written in the reduced form in the output, so e.g as 1/17 instead of 2/34), and then quickly I have realized the other solutions are another recurrence sequence, which I found was the Lucas sequence. So, essentially, I was staring at the numbers until I saw the pattern.

Comment: Your solution seems to go in the right direction. Approach you used is like I used. BUT. What about the recurrent relation $F_{n+4} = 3F_{n} - F_{n+2}$. It is not working.

Comment: @Wolfgang You are correct. I have messed up the indices on the RHS. They should be the other way around.

Comment: By the way, what is the meaning of $n$ in expressions with Fibonacci elements? It should not be the same as amount of vertexes in the polygon I think. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Wolfgang I don't know what the idea behind your formula is, but for mine it's the following: after one step, the fly will be at $v_1$ with probability 1/3, and from there probability of getting back to $v_0$ is P(1,n), or it goes to $v_{n-1}$ with probability 1/3 and returns with probability P(n-1,n).

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes, n is the same throughout and is the number of vertices in the polygon.

Comment: OK. I see you are correct about the total probability. But what about $n$? Why in expressions with Fib elements $n$ could not be larger than amount of vertexes? System would still solvable. And something more, in the system of equations it should be $-1/3$ on RHS I think.

Comment: @Wolfgang With $n$ changed things around $n/2$ would break. For example, if with $5$ vertices we chose $7$ in the formulas, we would assign $P(1,5)\dots,P(4,5)$ to be $L_4/L_6,L_2/L_6,L_2/L_6,L_4/L_6$, and these wouldn't satisfy the linear equation. As for $-1/3$, I agree, the ones to the right of the line should be $-1/3$. This is the reason why we get negative results in the solved matrix. It doesn't matter much, but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but let $n$ = 6. So if $k= n/2 = 3$ we should have $F_{1} = \frac{2F_{3}}{3}$ which is not true.

Comment: @Wolfgang Ah, good catch! $L$ and $F$ should be the other way around.

Comment: OK. I think I understand it all. Thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47609/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-wojowu).